# Wordpress Installation in Subfolder only works half

Tags: 404-error, installation

Hello I need to pick your brains here. So one of my projects went live a long time ago. The customer then asked me to build a second project which was supposed to be go live on a different domain. Not they aske dme to upload the project into a subfolder of their root. Everything is fine, I can access the admin and stuff, but the moment I open a blog post for example or navigate to one of the pages on their subfolder it automatically redirects me to the main domain.

I have checked the .htaccess which looks fine to me

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nameofnewsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /nameofnewsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after doing some more research I found out that I had to change the configs for the NGINX files as well.

I simply had to add the following parameters before the last closing bracket

```
location /nameofnewsite {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /nameofnewsite/index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/nameofnewsite)(/.*)$;
}
```